# Can I sell the original paperwork for a historically significant US patent?

Tags: documents, us1969999

I was wondering if the John W. Cuthbert Patent from August 14th, 1934 with the Air Compressor Units written on the patent is sellable. The numbers of this United States patent is (1969999)!

It happens to be in my possession and I don't know what to really do with it. I would like to sell it but I was wondering:

- Might it be worth anything?
- Is it legal to sell?

Answer (score 1):

> Might it be worth anything?

It's probably not worth a whole lot. According to my searches, John W. Cuthbert is not notable enough to have a Wikipedia article about him, nor are his contributions to air compressors widely enough recognized for his name to be associated with "air compressor history" in Google searches.

Nearest comparable I can find on eBay is selling for $50 (an 1885 patent related to vehicle springs).

> Is it legal to sell?

Assuming it's not stolen goods, yes.